# EXC_BAD_ACCESS : mySKPaymentTransaction.payment.productIdentifier

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

I am getting the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error on the below code

```
[self provideContent:mySKPaymentTransaction.payment.productIdentifier ];
```

I am assigning value to the mySKPaymentTransaction as below

```
- (void)recordTransaction:(SKPaymentTransaction *)transaction {

  mySKPaymentTransaction = transaction;
}
```

Please let me know why it is crashing...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the scope for the mySKPaymentTransaction is not present in

```
[self provideContent:mySKPaymentTransaction.payment.productIdentifier ];
```

If you did not initialize the mySKPaymentTransaction variable before assigning, please initialize it with 
    mySKPaymentTransaction = [[SKPaymentTransaction alloc] init];
and then assign.

If its not the case, then try retaining the transaction variable, instead of assigning it directly.

```
mySKPaymentTransaction = [transaction retain];
```

Comment: Thank  you. this one fixed mySKPaymentTransaction = [transaction retain]; what happens when retain is used?pls answer

Comment: As far as I know, it retains a copy of 'transaction' and then assign the copy to 'mySKPaymentTransaction', instead of pointing it towards the memory address of 'transaction'. Because of this, even if the memory location of 'transaction' becomes empty afterwards, it wont affect the 'mySKPaymentTransaction'.